Can anyone show me how to make a proper login system for my django application?
I need help building a proper login system for my homework in my django class. I am supposed to build an app that users can login in token based authentication and can post a destination and review it, but I'm stuck in the login section. I've manage to build the register systems correctly, but now I need to help with logging in.
This is my login view I have. It keeps throwing a "NOT NULL constraint failed: destination_session.user_id" error so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong
def login(request: HttpRequest):
if request.method == "POST":
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password_hash = request.POST.get('password')

    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    hasher.update(bytes(password_hash, "UTF-8"))
    password_hash = hasher.hexdigest()

    token = ""
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    for _ in range(32):
        token = "".join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(32))
    session_token = Session.objects.create(token=token)
    response = HttpResponse("Cookie Set")
    
    try: 
        user = User.objects.get(email=email, password_hash=password_hash)
        if user.check_password(password_hash):
            response = redirect("/")
            response.set_cookie('token', token)
            return response
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid password")
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return Http404({"Invalid email"})
    
return render(request, "destination/login.html")

Here are my models
from django.db import models
import hashlib

class User(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.TextField()
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
password_hash = models.TextField()

def check_password(self, hashed_password):
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    hasher.update(bytes(self.password_hash, "UTF-8"))
    hashed_password = hasher.hexdigest()
    return self.password_hash == hashed_password

class Session(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
token = models.TextField()

class Destination(models.Model):
id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
name = models.TextField()
review = models.TextField()
rating = models.PositiveIntegerField()
share_publicly = models.BooleanField(default=False)
user = models.ForeignKey("User", related_name="destinations", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

And here is my login form:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
        <label for="">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email">
        <label for="">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

If anyone can see what's wrong or help me find a better way I'd be appreciative. Also I'm not allowed to use the Auth, Session, or Admin built in modules so please don't suggest it. Bonus if you show me how to only show destinations from the logged in user xD

It's borderline impossible to tell for sure what the exact solution is if you don't include the full error message which details where the error occurs. Beyond that, a NOT NULL constraint means that you're trying to create a model instance without passing data to at least 1 field where data must be passed (because the model declaration doesn't specify null=True).

You are missing user while creating an Session -> session_token = Session.objects.create(token=token, user=??). Also, note that since its a one-to-one relation you need to check whether a session already exists for a given user before trying to create it again.

Well, a proper login is relative. The framework itself already has a proper login system out of the box, although its a session one.There are many different kinds of authentication systems. Nevertheless, based on your question you are asking about authentication with Tokens which is often used in API services. There are two standards, a plain Token Authentication or  a JWT - JSON Web Token Authentication
Usually, a developer does not waste time with such things. That is what libraries are for. Its always better to rely on such packages than implement for yourself, not just for agility but for security.
Relative to the User model, you are working against the framework , thus hindering yourself. If you want a custom user model, then you should do it properly. By not using the model provided by the framework, you are missing a lot of built-in features such as password hashing.
With that said, here is a shallow example of token auth:
models.py
class Token(models.Model):
    key = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expiration = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def is_expired(self):
        return True if timezone.now() > self.expiration else False

    def renew(self):
        """
        Renew a token key and makes it valid for 3hours
        its common for a obj to have a refresh_key in order
        to do this process, which would require more logic.
        """
        self.key = uuid.uuid4()
        self.expiration = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=3)
        self.save()

    def check_key(self, value):
        try:
            key = uuid.UUID(value)
            assert key == self.key
            return True

        except Exception:
            return False

views.py
def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        email = request.POST.get("email")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        token_key = request.COOKIES.get("token")

        try:
            # Fetch user and check password
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):

                # Verify token validity, renew if necessary
                token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
                if token.check_key(token_key):
                    if token.is_expired:
                        token.renew()

                    response = HttpResponse("Authentication Successfull")
                    response.set_cookie("token", token.key)
                    return response

                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Invalid Token")

            else:
                return HttpResponse("Wrong Password")

        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return HttpResponse("User Not Found.")

    else:
        return render(request, "login.html")

